# Making a list of a "master" dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, copy

I have a prototype dictionary that i want to use as a basis for appending to a list.
I want to change 1 or more values in the dictionary then capture it as an element of a list.

My question is this; is there any other recommended method for doing this short of using deepcopy().

I know this doesn't work properly:

```
    l = []
    d = {}
    d['key'] = 4
    l.append(d)
    d['key'] = 5
    l.append(d)
```

it gives:

l = [{'key': 5}, {'key': 5}]

it also didn't seem to work using a simply copy()

Comment: How about a function _creating_ a _new_ dictionary based on the parameters passed into the function?

Comment: That isn't really the issue - the starting dictionary has 3 base keys that have as their values dictionaries, and I am only changing 1 or 2 sub elements and adding a 4th key with a deeply nested dictionary list to each element but the basic info is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending a reference to the same object to both lists, so when you change the value of `"key"`, you change it in both lists.  You need to make a copy of the dictionary before appending if you want a separate reference, using the `dict.copy` function:

```
l = []
d = {}
d['key'] = 4
l.append(d.copy())
d['key'] = 5
l.append(d.copy())
```

If you need a deep copy, you can use the `copy` library:

```
import copy
l = []
d = {}
d['key'] = 4
l.append(copy.deepcopy(d))
d['key'] = 5
l.append(copy.deepcopy(d))
```

Comment: i tried a simple copy() but if the dictionary is mutilevel i thought it didnt work properly - i tried this example and it seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

`copy` should work.

```
l = []
d = {}
d['key'] = 4
l.append(d)
d = d.copy()
d['key'] = 5
l.append(d)
```

Result:

```
[{'key': 4}, {'key': 5}]
```

Comment: I will accept that this works for the example but I seem to remember something about deeper levels having reference issues unless you did a deep copy.